# MP4 Hotlink Protection For ASP.NET Or IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis

I'm protecting my MP4 files on my site from hotlinking by passing the request to a generic handler with code taken from here: [VideoStreamer Iphone/Ipad](http://videostreamer.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#VideoStreamer.ashx). The URL to the MP4 file is dynamic for each session, which is validated by the generic handler before the MP4 is streamed to the visitor.

It seems to work great for desktop browsers, but when testing on my Android, I'm unable to play the video. Might be worth noting that I'm routing my generic handler to a route such as `http://example.com/myroute/dynamicfilename.mp4` with a handler within my web.config to deal with all requests for .mp4 files.

Without routing, the playback works on the Android phone using the same code. Hence, I suspect that this has got something to do with the route. Maybe that I'm handling an MP4 file extension?

Any thoughts? Is there some other/better/recommended way to do this (maybe using `context.rewrite`?) or some other method in IIS that is similar to `httpd mod_secdownload`?

Comment: Is the handler returning video/mp4 as the content type?

Comment: yes, it is returning video/mp4

Comment: Can you sniff the wire for working and not working HTTP requests from the Android device and see what the difference is?

Comment: Yes, I did sniff the packets and found out that my generic handler started giving 404s after a couple of requests or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Android (maybe iOS too) video player app at some point stops using the session passed by the browser. Hence, the first request that uses the session is valid, while the second request by the video player app receives a 404 because my generic handler could not validate the dynamically generated URL. No solution here, but it might help if somebody ends up into a similar puzzle in the future.